# Implementing WPF Map Control in Microsoft Surface

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am implementing the WPF Map Control ([this one](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=27165)) for a Surface application. In Visual Studio 2012 I created a WPF solution and made the implementation. I am able to run the code in my local machine, it uses HttpClient to query a Web-API, retrieve the coordinates and mark the pinpoints.

I know something has to be done before been able to test my development on a Surface but I am really confused. In some pages I read it had to be done with blend ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727733.aspx)), I tried that but could use the httpClient there, some page said I had to made the development in a Surface Application (WPF) ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727780.aspx)) but I can't find that template, I searched the web, NuGet, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft does have another Bing Maps SDK for Surface apps ([here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Bing-Maps-SDK-for-Metro-31b378eb/view/SamplePack#content)) so I dont have to do the WPF implementation. It is very easy to use and does the work pretty well.